# Which, if any, of the major console game developers also develop for Android?

Tags: google-play-store

The Android market has a lot of apps now, and for the most part almost anything that could only be done on the iPhone a couple of years ago is now possible on Android. The app stores have become quite competitive and comparable.

However, one thing that appears to be missing from the Android Market are major console game developers. iOS, for example, has many titles by publishers such as Electronic Arts, SEGA, and Square Enix. Some of these are ports of console games (like Sonic the Hedgehog), and some of them are made-for-mobile games (like Square Enix's Chaos Rings). I don't see anything from those publishers in the Android Market.

So, my question is **are there, in fact, any major console-game developers/publishers currently selling games in the official Android Market**? If not, is there any reason to believe this might change?

Note that my question is about Google's Android Marketplace and does not include any 3rd party markets. I'm aware that Electronic Arts is selling apps in Amazon's store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gameloft](http://www.gameloft.com/) has been reluctant to publish on Android Market because of their own DRM policies, but lately they have been changing their stance and putting more of their games on [Android Market](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Gameloft).

[EA](http://www.ea.com/) has plenty of titles [up for sale](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Electronic%20Arts%20Inc.) as well (in Europe, see [EA Netherlands](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Electronic%20Arts%20Nederland%20BV)).

Some other big names like [iD Software](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/08/16/id-software-bring-rage-android/) and [Epic](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/09/15/unreal-engine-headed-to-android/) have mentioned a strong possibility of bringing ports to the likes of Rage and Unreal Engine to Android some time in the future as well.

And then of course, there's [Zynga](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Zynga), if you're not getting enough spam from their apps on Facebook.

Comment: Square Enix and Sega have several now, too.

Answer (score 3):

How did you search for the publishers? Electronic Arts, for example, [most certainly has applications in the Market](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Electronic+Arts+Inc.). I only see [one Square Enix game](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=SQUARE%20ENIX%20Co.,Ltd.), though.

Beyond that, the [Xperia Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_Xperia_Play) will be supported by a line of Playstation titles. [They're already starting to hit the market](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Sony%20Computer%20Entertainment%20America), in fact. I wouldn't recommend purchasing them unless you own an Xperia Play since I have no idea what running them on a non-suported device would entail (or if it's even feasible - I'll leave that to XDA), but it's another angle to it.

Whether or not they'll continue to update them or develop new games...I could only speculate, really.